# What is the best way to map arrays and not allow future developers to mess it up?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

Lets say I have an array `array('VI', 'MC', 'AE')` and an array `array('V', 'M', 'E')` I want to map the arrays so that later on if I get the data of VI I can use that to get V. I used the array_map function to do this. But what if someone later on goes in and changes the order of my first array or adds one to it and doesn't change the second, it could mess up the mapping. What is the best way to handle this to make sure there isn't any mistake in the future.

Here is an example of my code. One thing to note, I have hard coded the arrays but these are really grabbed from methods that are grabbing from configuration values, so yes it is different then just having both arrays defined right in the method

```
 private function _getMethodFromMageType($mageType){
    $origCCTypes =  array('VI', 'MC', 'AE');
    $newCCTypes = array('V', 'M', 'E');
    $typesMap = array_map(array(&$this, 'mapCCTypes'), $origCCTypes, $newCCTypes);

    foreach ($typesMap as $key => $map){
        if($map[$origType]){
            return $map[$origType];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my call back function for the array_map function

```
private function mapCCTypes($ccTypes1, $ccTypes2){
    return (array($ccTypes1 => $ccTypes2));
}
```

Comment: The best way to prevent most programming errors is unit testing. Write a test case. If it passes, it's all good. If it fails, then someone "messed up the code" (or just didn't update the test to reflect his legitimate changes). Rollback, fix the code, slap him/her, whatever. :)

Comment: Comment this method and explain that the arrays should be in a certain format.

Comment: Hey Rocket, that is what I figured was my most basic approach, was seeing if there was something I could do that was a little stronger then that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a bit ugly, but if you're concerned about it, you can make the code more resistant to tinkering with the order of the config lists by hardcoding the current, known mappings and using those in preference to an order-based mapping where available:

```
private $ccStaticMap = array(
    'VI' => 'V',
    'MC' => 'M',
    'AE' => 'E',
);

private function _getMethodFromMageType($origType) {
    $origCCTypes = pullOrigTypesFromConfig();
    $newCCTypes = pullNewTypesFromConfig();
    foreach($this->ccStaticMap as $key => $val) {
        while(($ix = array_search($key, $origCCTypes)) !== false)
            unset($origCCTypes[$ix]);
        while(($ix = array_search($val, $newCCTypes)) !== false)
            unset($newCCTypes[$ix]);
    }
    $typesMap = $this->ccStaticMap;
    for($ix = 0; $ix < min(count($origCCTypes), count($newCCTypes)); $ix++)
        $typesMap[$origCCTypes[$ix]] = $newCCTypes[$ix];
    return isset($typesMap[$origType]) ? $typesMap[$origType] : null;
}
```

Comment: This works, to make it so if someone adds a cc type to the begininning you can't have a bad match, but it does assign the value of the correct one to the new cc type. Like if you added DI at the first index it would get the value of V after the array_map function. Do you think this is fine?

Comment: Thinking about it, you could get some additional value out of it by pulling the keys of `$ccStaticMap` out of `$origCCTypes` and the values out of `$newCCTypes`.  That way any newly added types will, at the least, only get mapped to other new types.

Comment: Thanks I will play around with that.

Comment: actually I am a little confused if you were to pull the keys from the `$origCCTypes` and values out of `$newCCTypes` aren't you with the same problem of knowing what value maps to what key?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do things a little differently, using `$ccStaticMap` as a starting point.  Actually, here, I'll just edit my answer to be my actual recommendation, sec. :)

Answer (score 2):

Only have one array which directly stores the mappings in a clear way:

```
$CCTypes = array('VI' => 'V', 'MC' => 'M', 'AE' => 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Why don't you [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine)? That's simpler than your `array_map` approach, if I correctly understood what it does.

b) Why don't you use an associative array right away?

Comment: I can answer b: because, as OP mentions in the question, the arrays are being pulled from an external config source and aren't under his direct control.

Comment: @chaos: Still the external source could define associative arrays, couldn't it?

Comment: Who knows?  Either way, I think part of the constraints on the problem is that OP can't change the external source.

Comment: Yes, the problem with that is the system needs the configuration to be set a certain way for the origal types and I am integrating into a third party system that has its own abbreviation for the same types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can avoid that if your mappings come from configuration files. You can always mess up configuration files (and then you will have to save the original mappings somewhere to see if it has been messed up). Maybe you need to improve your configuration parsing or declaration process so that you always have to declare some kind of associative array e.g. in an INI file:

```
mappings.VI = V
mappings.MC = M
mappings.AE = E

$data = parse_ini_file("file.ini");
$mappings = $data['mappings'];
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to change this at the time.

Comment: Then you will have to hardcode the original mappings and merge/overwrite them with the version from your configuration.